# How Youtrack behaves with cascade workflows?

Tags: youtrack

This is rather technical question.
In Youtrack I can create rather complicated workflow rules(for example lets play with Stateless rules). 
When first rule is executed, it can change some data, that triggers second rule. Second rule may trigger  third rule. And at last third rule may trigger first rule again.

What mechanism Youtrack uses under the hood to avoid infinite loops? How many loops can occur?

As far as I've checked, if rule is executed second time during rules applying, execution is stopped. Is this correct?

Also I have another question : if first rule changes some data, and second rule requires some field to be set, will first rule be applied even if second failes? Here I'm interested about transaction scope of rules application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number of workflow execution iterations is limited to 10, where each iteration includes processing changes made either by a user or by a workflow rule.

As for your second question. Changes made by all wf rules are atomic, meaning that if one rule fails, all changes made by WF are reverted.